# Add header to outgoing email with postfix

Tags: email, postfix

Can someone please provide *an example* on how to add a

> Precedence: bulk

header to all outgoing emails using postfix.

I would like to know what file(s) to create or edit and what I should put in them. And also what to do to make postfix read in the new configuration.

I have read quite a bit of documentation but it seems to expect a high level of familiarity with postfix. All I have gathered so far is that it may have something to do with `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and somehow add a PREPEND statement.

Note that mucking about with postfix (and email in general) is way out of my comfort zone.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, this isn't super straightforward in postfix, but certainly doable.

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**, set header_checks to:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/my_custom_header
```

Then create **/etc/postfix/my_custom_header** and put this regular expression in it:

```
/^Content-Transfer-Encoding:/i PREPEND Precedence: bulk
```

Then restart postfix - depends on your distro, but most likely you can restart it with `service postfix restart` or `/etc/init.d/postfix restart`.

Thats about it.  What this does is that postfix will find the `Content-Transfer-Encoding:` header in the email and add your `Precedence: bulk` line right before it, hence the `PREPEND` action.

Now, this assumes that the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header actually exists in the emails.  You may want to take a look at the headers on a typical outgoing email and find a good one to match upon.  You can get crazy with the [regex](http://aiti.mit.edu/media/programs/ghana-summer-2012/materials/regex_cheatsheet.pdf) to suit your needs.